# Issue bringing SVG file into Openscad

Tags: openscad

I am using the following Code to turn a somewhat complicated SVG file into a 3D plate for the letterpress printing process.  I get a mesh error when I can find no issues within the SVG itself. All of the paths are closed.

I added the Offset(delta=0.001) and that seemed to help on simple SVG's with simple shapes or a small amount of text.  But I have been processing the SVG that I am attaching here for over 12 hours and it seems to be stuck somewhere. (Screenshot Attached)

[scad screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl1YN.jpg)

```
file = "InviteFinal.svg";
width = 139.7;
height = 215.9;

feature_height = 1.143;
plate_thickness = 0.254;

union()
{
    minkowski()
    {
        linear_extrude(height = 0.1, center = false, convexity = 10)
        scale([-1, 1, 1])
        translate([-width, 0, 0])
        offset(delta=0.001)
        import(file);
        
        
        cylinder(feature_height - 0, 0.25, 0);
    }
    
    translate([-10,-10,-0.254])
    cube([width+20,height+20,plate_thickness]);

    minkowski()
    {
        union()
        {
            translate([width+5,height,0])
            cube([5,0.8,0.2],true);

            translate([width,height+5,0])
            cube([0.8,5,0.2], true);


            translate([-5,0,0])
            cube([5,0.8,0.2],true);

            translate([0,-5,0])
            cube([0.8,5,0.2], true);


            translate([width+5,0,0])
            cube([5,0.8,0.2],true);

            translate([width,-5,0])
            cube([0.8,5,0.2], true);


            translate([-5,height,0])
            cube([5,0.8,0.2],true);

            translate([0,height+5,0])
            cube([0.8,5,0.2], true);
        }
        
        cylinder(feature_height - 0.1, 0.2, 0);
    }
}
```

[SVG file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CF8XPyAvCFataIQRn7xu6x-E0QLhEGI-/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first minkowski() sum on the extruded text and the cylinder. The purpose of doing a minkowski() sum is to round the corners on objects. The more corners there are the longer it takes. So for things like the letter 'O' it will take a long time.

From the OpenSCAD documentation for [minkowski](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Transformations#minkowski):

> Warning: for high values of $fn the minkowski sum may end up consuming
> lots of CPU and memory, since it has to combine every child node of
> each element with all the nodes of each other element. So if for
> example $fn=100 and you combine two cylinders, then it does not just
> perform 200 operations as with two independent cylinders, but 100*100
> = 10000 operations.

To troubleshoot I removed the second half of the file from the second minkowski sum on down. That locked up OpenSCAD and I had to close it. When I removed the first minkowski() sum so that just the svg was extruded it rendered in 5 seconds. What effect are you trying to achieve by doing a minkowski sum on the svg?